# Atajo para esta funcion en sublimetext

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Usando sublime text 3, por error hice un bloque de comentario con este estilo, y me gustò mucho Me gustarìa saber como se hacen y como se llama este estilo de comentario .[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Traduce tu pregunta al Español asi es mejor recibida.

Comment: Sì, disculpa, pesè que estaba en laravel en inglès